# Logback: gracefully split messages at 64k

Tags: java, logback

We have a log collecting service that automatically splits messages at 64KB, but the split is not elegant at all.  We are printing individual log messages as json blobs with some additional metadata.  Sometimes these include large stack traces that we want to preserve in full.

So I was looking into writing a custom logger or appender wrapper that would take the message and split it into smaller chunks and re-log it but that's looking non-trivial.

Is there a simple way to configure logback to split up its messages into multiple separate messages if the size of the message is greater than some value?

Here is the appender configuration:

```
<!-- Sumo optimized rolling log file -->
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <Append>true</Append>
    <file>${log.dir}/${service.name}-sumo.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <fieldName>t</fieldName>
                <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'</pattern>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <message/>
            <loggerName/>
            <threadName/>
            <logLevel/>
            <stackTrace>
                <if condition='isDefined("throwable.converter")'>
                    <then>
                        <throwableConverter class="${throwable.converter}"/>
                    </then>
                </if>
            </stackTrace>
            <mdc/>
            <tags/>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
        <FileNamePattern>${log.dir}/${service.name}-sumo.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>256MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

<appender name="sumo" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>500</queueSize>
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</appender>
```

Comment: that's an interesting question. I don't think there is anything standard for this, at least I can't find any. what if you did the split of multiple lines messages yourself and used mapped diagnostic context with some unique id to be able correlate them

Comment: this thread is discussing a custom layout like that http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2009-September/001317.html

Comment: @MarianP we already have a correlationid for linking messages related to a single web transaction, so I didn't have to do anything with that.  I added code below that wraps the logger and accomplishes my goal.  Not as elegant as calling `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` but it does the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with is simply to wrap my logger in something that splits up messages nicely.  Note that I'm primarily interested in splitting messages with `Throwable`s since those are what causes long messages.

Written with lambdas for Java 8

Also note this code is not fully tested, I'll update it if I find any bugs.

```
public class MessageSplittingLogger extends MarkerIgnoringBase {
    //Target size is 64k for split.  UTF-8 nominally has 1 byte characters, but some characters will use > 1 byte so leave some wiggle room
    //Also leave room for additional messages
    private static final int MAX_CHARS_BEFORE_SPLIT = 56000;
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private Logger LOGGER;

    public MessageSplittingLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
    }

    private void splitMessageAndLog(String msg, Throwable t, Consumer<String> logLambda) {
        String combinedMsg = msg + (t != null ? "\nStack Trace:\n" + printStackTraceToString(t) : "");

        int totalMessages = combinedMsg.length() / MAX_CHARS_BEFORE_SPLIT;
        if(combinedMsg.length() % MAX_CHARS_BEFORE_SPLIT > 0){
            totalMessages++;
        }

        int index = 0;
        int msgNumber = 1;
        while (index < combinedMsg.length()) {
            String messageNumber = totalMessages > 1 ? "(" + msgNumber++ + " of " + totalMessages + ")\n" : "";
            logLambda.accept(messageNumber + combinedMsg.substring(index, Math.min(index + MAX_CHARS_BEFORE_SPLIT, combinedMsg.length())));
            index += MAX_CHARS_BEFORE_SPLIT;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the stack trace as a String
     */
    private String printStackTraceToString(Throwable t) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true, ENCODING);
            t.printStackTrace(ps);

            return baos.toString(ENCODING);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return "Exception printing stack trace: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return LOGGER.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
        return LOGGER.isTraceEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(String msg) {
        LOGGER.trace(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(String format, Object arg) {
        LOGGER.trace(format, arg);
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        LOGGER.trace(format, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(String format, Object... arguments) {
        LOGGER.trace(format, arguments);
    }

    @Override
    public void trace(String msg, Throwable t) {
        splitMessageAndLog(msg, t, LOGGER::trace);
    }

    //... Similarly wrap calls to debug/info/error
}
```